# How to automatically generate an implementor of an interface in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

In Eclipse I can create a class with stub methods auto-generated for an interface. Surely this works in Visual Studio somehow, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.  Type the interface name as usual and look for a smart tag to pop underneath the interface name.  Expand that and it will give you menu options for implementing the interface.

The keyboard shortcut for this is `Control + .`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article on the code refactoring functionality in Visual Studio 2005.

[Refactoring C# Code Using Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379618.aspx#vs05_refac_topic5)

Answer (score 1):

Type the name of the interface and either right click it (using the smart tag), or, my personal favorite, press ctrl + point.  (No need to reach for the mouse ;) ).

Answer (score -1):

In vb.net you just write class name
implement interface [press enter here]

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The question does not tell what language he wanted help for and in VB.net its just a enter away!